# Multi-pattern nested regex using Python re

Tags: python, regex, sed

What is an equivalent way to write this sed program in Python using the re library? This sed pattern completes the search in one pass and its efficient. I am trying to extract the model number of the cpu. Please see my Python code attempt at the bottom.

Sample input:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 45
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping        : 6
```

Output:

```
E5-2660
```

Sample input 2:

```
processor       : 127
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 23
model           : 1
model name      : AMD EPYC 7601 32-Core Processor
stepping        : 2
```

Output:

```
EPYC 7601
```

Sed:

```
/AuthenticAMD/{
    s/.*/AMD/p
}
/GenuineIntel/ {
    n
    n
    n
    /Celeron/ {            
        s/.*\([egptEGPT][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\).*/\1/p 
        s/.*\([egptEGPT][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]\).*/\1/p 
        s/.*\([egptEGPT][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/p
        q
    }
    /Xeon/ {
        s/.*[eE][3579]-\([1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]\).*/\1/p
        s/.*\([eElL]C[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/p
        s/.*\([35][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/p
        q
    }
}
```

Attempt in Python (not working):

My code searches every expression and doesn't follow any nesting rules, which is not efficient. Looking for a better way to write this.

```
string = """processor       : 0
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 45
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz
            stepping        : 6"""

pattern = r'''GenuineIntel.*
                (?=Celeron
                    .*([egptEGPT][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]).*
                    .*([egptEGPT][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]).*
                    .*([egptEGPT][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*)|
                (?=Xeon
                    .*([eE][3579]-[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*)'''

print(re.search(pattern, string, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL|re.VERBOSE).groups())
```

Comment: looks ok to me, as long as it works.  Maybe write ``[0-9][0-9][0-9]`` as ``\d{3}`` instead and use the ignore case flag

Comment: In your `sed`, shouldn't `/AuthenticAMC/{` be `/AuthenticAMD/{`? Also, what about the `[1-9]`s in `[eE][3579]-\([1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]\)`? Are you sure it is not `[eE][3579]-\([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)`?

Comment: Also, I doubt your `sed` command works, see https://ideone.com/NSIPMF. You say the output should be `EPYC 7601`, but - as per the `sed` command logic - the output is `AMD`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback updated the question.  Although my main objective is to be able to write the regex in python such that it checks if "Celeron" exists, if it does not, then it skips searching the regular expressions within Celeron and moves onto the next which is "Xeon". Currently, I think the python code I wrote checks every single nested expression? Am i wrong?

Comment: Currently, the regex requires both `Celeron` and `Xeon` to appear to the right of `GenuineIntel`. I wrote a direct translation for the sed command in Python, but it does not return what you expect.

Comment: Yes the reg exp for AMD is not setup yet, I will do that later, its not important. The sed and python will only work properly for Intel right now.

Comment: With the first sample input in my question, is my python code executing all of the  Celeron regular expressions before it gets to executing the Xeon regular expressions?

Comment: There is only 1 regex pattern in your Python code. It is just wrong.

Comment: Just in case you are interested: this is your regex - `Authentic(AMD)|GenuineIntel(?:.*\n){3}.*?(?:Celeron.*?([egptEGPT][1-9]\d{3}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})|Xeon.*?((?:[eE][3579]-[1-9]|[eElL]C[1-9]|[35])\d{3}))`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kMV9Mr/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having fully featured language like Python and so well structured data I wouldn't try to parse everything using regular expressions. Instead I'd just wrote a code doing the job, using regex only at the very end. This way instead of enormous regex, I have short and easy to read code with very simple regular expressions.

```py
data = {}
for line in string.split("\n"):
    left, right = line.split(":")
    data[left.strip()] = right.strip()

if data["vendor_id"] == "GenuineIntel":
    model = data["model name"]
    if "Xeon" in model:
        code = re.search(r"\bE\d-\d{4}\b", model, re.I).group(0)
    elif "Celeron" in model:
        code = re.search(r"\b[EGPT]\d{4}[a-z]{0,2}\b", model, re.I).group(0)

print(code)
```

About efficiency - as long as you don't have millions of strings to parse, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I like the way you split the fields in  the input string and how you condensed the regex statements into one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind the good advice at https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/, don't base your python code on the sed script, start with something nice and simple like this awk script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^vendor_id/ {
    vendor = $NF
}
/^model name/ {
    model = "Unknown"
    if ( vendor == "GenuineIntel" ) {
        model = $7
    }
    else if ( vendor == "AuthenticAMD" ) {
        model = $5 " " $6
    }
    print model
}
```

which I'm sure you can trivially implement in python too. Here's an example of it working with your 2 blocks of sample input in one file:

```
$ cat file
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 45
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping        : 6

processor       : 127
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 23
model           : 1
model name      : AMD EPYC 7601 32-Core Processor
stepping        : 2

$ awk -f tst.awk file
E5-2660
EPYC 7601
```